# Need help CLEANING UP! Jquery iterating through loop, adding unique classes, mapping array

Tags: jquery, loops, dry, code-cleanup

The code I have works, but it's not concise and there is a lot of repeating. Looking for someone more knowledgeable to help me clean this up so I can do the same with less code and learn in the process.

I started with this coming through on my page for each loop element (5 total):

```
<div class="rec-topics">[Topic One, Topic Two, Topic Three]</div>
```

I needed to use jQuery to remove the brackets and commas, then wrap it in an unordered list with each one being its own list item. That way I could style through CSS for the client.

Here's the code I wrote (which works), but I know there is a ton of repetition and it could be much cleaner.

```
//Add unique class to each loop element
$('.rec-topics').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('postlist' + (i+1));
});

//Create a variable for each unique class on each loop iteration
var div = $('.postlist1');
var div2 = $('.postlist2');
var div3 = $('.postlist3');
var div4 = $('.postlist4');
var div5 = $('.postlist5');

//Post Items - remove braket on left
div.html(div.html().replace(/\[/g, ''));
div2.html(div2.html().replace(/\[/g, ''));
div3.html(div3.html().replace(/\[/g, ''));
div4.html(div4.html().replace(/\[/g, ''));
div5.html(div5.html().replace(/\[/g, ''));

//Post Items - remove braket on right
div.html(div.html().replace(/\]/g, ''));
div2.html(div2.html().replace(/\]/g, ''));
div3.html(div3.html().replace(/\]/g, ''));
div4.html(div4.html().replace(/\]/g, ''));
div5.html(div5.html().replace(/\]/g, ''));

//Post Item 1 - split each element with commas to create an array. Map array and create unordered list.
var values = div.html().split(',');
div.html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
  return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');

//Post Item 2 - split each element with commas to create an array. Map array and create unordered list.
var values = div2.html().split(',');
div2.html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
  return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');

//Post Item 3 - split each element with commas to create an array. Map array and create unordered list.
var values = div3.html().split(',');
div3.html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
  return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');

//Post Item 4 - split each element with commas to create an array. Map array and create unordered list.
var values = div4.html().split(',');
div4.html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
  return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');

//Post Item 5 - split each element with commas to create an array. Map array and create unordered list.
var values = div5.html().split(',');
div5.html('<ul>' + $.map(values, function(v) { 
  return '<li>' + v + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because working code does not belong on SO.  Try [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Is that HTML snippet at the top your full HTML, what did the inner div's originally contain?

Comment: Just need to reformat the contents inside .rec-topics. There are multiple iterations of .rec-topics with different topics inside each. I originally had something like Barmar suggested below, but it took the first topic list & overwrote all the remaining elements.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the elements with the same class.

You don't need two separate calls to `.replace()`, you can remove the initial `[` and trailing `]` with a single call.

```js
$(".rec-topics").html(function(i, oldHtml) {
  var items = oldHtml.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '').split(',');
  return '<ul>' + $.map(items, function(value) {
    return '<li>' + value + '</li>';
  }).join('') + '</ul>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rec-topics">[Topic One, Topic Two, Topic Three]</div>
<div class="rec-topics">[Topic Four, Topic Five, Topic Six]</div>
```

Comment: I originally had something like this but what it would do is take the first post element and force those results on all subsequent loop elements.

Comment: That said, I tried using your code and it did not work for me.

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific, I did use your comment to combine removing brackets with one replace call now, so thank you for that. But the rest didn't take initially. I'll keep playing with it. I still think I need unique classes thought because of it overwriting from the first post.

Comment: If it's overwriting from the first post, you must be using a selector inside the loop instead of referring to the current loop element.

Comment: Yes, I think so. That's why I added a unique class to each loop iteration so I could target each one specifically. I know it's not perfect though, that's why I'm trying to clean it up somehow.

Comment: Show the code you tried in your question, then I can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I have it but I don't know how to add code to a comment? It won't let me format it?

Comment: You need to put a function in the `.html()` call so that it calls that function on each element. That function receives the old HTML of the element as an argument, and it returns the new HTML.